# Zero Pad an integer array when printed to textbox

Tags: visual-studio, c#, forms

I have an array of Integers however want to print them to a textbox within my form application so that they all look the same in length and it looks neat. How would i go about zero-padding the 100 integers present in my array(ranging in value from 1 to 1000) and outputting the zero padded array at once to a textbox?

Currently my program will display like:

`1,2,...,1000`

however id like to be able to do it like:

`0001,0002,...,1000`.

The code i use to print to the textbox is:

```
`array = new int[1000];    //create an array
 Random randNum = new Random();    //create an instance of random Number
 for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)    //Generate random array
 {
      array[i] = randNum.Next(0, 1000);
 }
 SetupLabel.Text = (string.Join(" ", array));    //output all of the array at once as a string`
```

Any ideas would help a lot, thanks.

Comment: Without using a monospace font, they still won’t have the same rendered dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach is to use Composite Formatting or String Interpolation to do the "zero padding" for you.

```
        int[] array = new int[1000];    //create an array
        Random randNum = new Random();    //create an instance of random Number
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)    //Generate random array
        {
            int r = randNum.Next(0, 1000);
            sb.Append($"{r:0000},");
        }
        SetupLabel.Text = sb.ToString();
```

The ":0000" means to pad the value with at least 4 zeros

Answer (score 0):

[Padding Strings in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66f6d830(v=vs.110).aspx)

Using `String.PadLeft` or (not applicable in your example) `String.PadRight`. Your example output is also wrong as your code would generate a list separated by white spaces rather than commas. To use `StringPadLeft` you would first have to create an intermediate string object which to which you consecutively add the padded number.